# Not able to scrape details using bs4, python, selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using the below code to print the soup variable that is nothing but the source code of the page.

**Code**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json, requests, re, sys
from selenium import webdriver
import re, time


yes_url = "https://www.yesbank.in/personal-banking/yes-first/cards/credit-card/yes-first-exclusive-credit-card"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Hari\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(yes_url)
time.sleep(3)

# r = requests.get(yes_url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
print(soup)


driver.close()
```

Link I am scraping the page source from is : https://www.yesbank.in/personal-banking/yes-first/cards/credit-card/yes-first-exclusive-credit-card

After running the above code the code keeps running till hours and hours but I don't get the output.

Please help me in scraping the page source, so that I get some output after I run the code.

Comment: This is what I get:



Access Denied



You don't have permission to access "http://www.yesbank.in/personal-banking/yes-first/cards/credit-card/yes-first-exclusive-credit-card" on this server.

Comment: @ Rocket Nikita So I need a way to bypass that and be able to access the source code of the page.

Comment: Can you tell us which part of the page you want to scrape?

Comment: @bilakos I want to scrape the details of the benefits tab in that page.

Comment: @MaredpallyJalebi ok I'm gonna give it a try

Comment: @ bilakos Sure, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**: You are dealing with a modern website which check the browser itself if it's controlled or not using robust.

> How That can be done?

Simply, open your browser console and then type the following:

```
navigator.webdriver
```

if it's `false` so your browser isn't contorlled by any robust program such as `selenium`.

if it's `true` so it's controlled.

In your case, you've to disable it in order to trick the website checking mechanism.

Below you can achieve your goal:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.yesbank.in/personal-banking/yes-first/cards/credit-card/yes-first-exclusive-credit-card')


try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.title_contains('YES'))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    print(soup.prettify())
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: @ αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη Can I do the same in a chrome browser ?

Comment: Yes ! options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

Comment: @ αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη Could you write the code for the same please, I tried to execute but I am getting error.